# Reputation point system is ridiculous

Tags: discussion, reputation

The reputation point system is useless. Why would i need reputation points to answer a question or to create a tag? People should have the freedom to use just about any tag they want and should be able to post any answer they want. It's all ridiculous! Reputation points should just be for users to judge other users.

If this reputation system wasn't repaired:
on a different topic, somebody suggested that the "split" tag should be killed. Guys do not kill tags as other people who just joined might find them useful.

Edit: Why am i getting so many down votes?
Edit: Vote up if you agree that the reputation system is baloney!

Tags that never could make it:
reputation point system is dumb stupid pointless ridiculous

Edit: I got all the answers i wanted. no more complaints are needed.

Comment: I'm a mod. I have Powers Beyond User Comprehension. I'd also add your SU and MSU meta accounts are linked so you automatically get control of a moved question. We don't *encourage* folks to do it though.

Comment: Wait, so you were trying to create the tags "reputation point system is dumb stupid pointless ridiculous"? Looks like the system is doing its job and keeping out inappropriate tags, then.

Comment: I will request you, not to be so aggressive. SU has a system in place and those who are willing to follow it can do it. There are other forums for those who do not like it here....

Comment: @Prasanna the post is now outdated. I was already told that it is to stop annoying people from being, well, annoying. I just want to raise a bit of quest

Comment: I figured answering questions or raising disscusions is'nt my type. I think i might just delete this entire post later on

Comment: @FluorescentGreen - Since it has an answer you won't be able to delete your question.

Comment: Someone delete this question for me!

Comment: alright, ill leave it here

Comment: It is. That's why +1 from my side.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reputation point system is really designed to ease people into learning to use the site effectively and eventually metamoderation tasks. While it shouldn't be punitive in theory, sometimes it is - especially when something is clearly out of scope. On main sites, question downvotes often indicate a lack of research, information, or something that simply isn't within the scope of the site. We often edit questions for new users if the issues are minor, and comment on how to make things better. Sometimes something simply isn't in scope

Using the *appropriate* tags is important because it makes it easier to find specific sorts of questions. We clear out bad tags cause its noise. As a new user, if you really *need* a tag, and can make a case for it, it'll be added. However [reputation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/reputation) [point](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/point) [system](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system) [is](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/is) [dumb](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dumb) [stupid](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/stupid) [pointless](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pointless) [ridiculous](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ridiculous) are textbook invalid tags - tags are like salt. A little goes a long way, too much causes high blood pressures. [discussion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/discussion) will do nicely. This is PRECISELY why you need reputation to post tags.

The problem with your *original* question is really that its essentially a broad purchase recommendation. While there's workarounds, there's no real way to post a proper, universal answer to handle 'why is my computer slow'. we *typically* handle this on chat, but yes, it kind of sucks that you can't do that, but once again, that low barrier of entry keeps spammers and all but the most persistent trolls out.

Handling a high traffic site isn't easy. We have a fairly large team of moderators, we have community mods, and people *still* do things like use tags we've asked them not to use.

Getting rep isn't hard. As I pointed out, you need ONE quality answer, or a good question. I've always pointed folk at ESR's [asking questions the smart way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) or you could do what I did and look around. (I've asked bad questions. It isn't the end of the world).

The reputation system lets us do a few things. Firstly, its our first line of defence against spammers. Secondly, it ensures quality to an extent. Finally, people love imaginary internet points.

I'd add, that the reputation point system is *integral* to how we do things here. Get used to it, work out how we do things, and you'll get a lot more out of the site.

Comment: you make a good point. programming is my hobby, so i think ill stick to stack overflow

Comment: @FluorescentGreen You realize that Stack Overflow runs on the exact same engine and is backed up by the same community team and principles?

Comment: Someone delete this question for me!

Answer (score 4):

Superuser is very much concerned about serving the best to the users who put their queries here. Also it helps to prevent spammers to drop their links on this website. Spammers do not have enough time to build their reputation. You need to prove your caliber to help others. It also helps the users to filter among the most popular and active user.

I don't think it's bad, rather i feel it makes you motivated at every up vote to help more and share as much as you could

Comment: yeah i guess ur right. but it would be nice if u dont need reputation to vote. on youtube anyone with an account can vote

Comment: Actually its often seen that people try to build their reputation on their own, to avoid this, reputation system is implemented, You may bookmark the page for future and once you reach that level, you may up vote the answer you liked. I did the same :)

Comment: @FluorescentGreen: We've had to clear out voting rings and puppets in the past. A few people ruin it for everyone in this case.

Comment: @FluorescentGreen - If anyone can vote on TouTube you basically have indicated that the vote system on YouTube means nothing.

Comment: actually the vote system is accurate on youtube. most good videos have alot of likes. when a video has lots of dislikes, the video turns out to be bad. for example, videos made by 8 year old kids turn out to be dumb and are raided with dislikes. videos made by popular youtubers turn out to be good. not trying to argue or anything just point out this

Comment: Someone delete this question for me!

Comment: @FluorescentGreen - Why? The question is valid.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the question you originally asked was how to game on a 6 year-old laptop that was cheap even in it's day.  I really hope you see the irony of criticizing the reputation system on a question like that.

More to the point, the low-level privileges are tied to reputation primarily for troll prevention.  It doesn't take much effort to earn enough reputation to participate in the SU community. The bar is set so low that you only need one quality question or answer and you're in the club.  But it's more effort than 95% of trolls are willing to put in, and that's fortunate for the rest of us. (Note that I am not calling you a troll).

Also, the tag system needs to be clean and efficient.  It's not like Twitter where you can hashtag any cutesy saying you want.  As a contributor to the community, the tags are the best way to find relevant questions for which you know the answer.  Tags like "reputation point system is dumb stupid pointless ridiculous" don't help people do that.

This is a harsh lesson to learn for a new user on a site like this, but your question was entirely self-serving.  You earn reputation by being useful to others.  The only person who cares about gaming on an old POS laptop is you.

Comment: I feel like deleting this question now that it has been answered

Comment: It might be useful for the next guy who wonders the same thing though. If you absolutely need it deleted, feel free to flag it instead of commenting on every single answer.